# (Android) Add image subviews to each tile in TileView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I implemented

https://github.com/moagrius/TileView

successfully.

Is it possible to have 2 layers of tile image for each tile?

Each tile in TileView would have 2 views that would use different image depending on its zoom scale.

**From:** (Normal usage of TileView)

```
TileView
  - Tile0
      - View A0
  - Tile1
      - View A1
  - Tile2
      - View A2
    ...
```

**To:**

```
TileView
  - Tile0
      - View A0
      - View B0
  - Tile1
      - View A1
      - View B1
  - Tile2
      - View A2
      - View B2
    ...
```

Comment: Maybe try directly creating an issue in the repository, the creator may be able to help you better. https://github.com/moagrius/TileView/issues/new

Comment: @DanielDiekmeier okay thanks!